# Getting string expected error for source_id even though the source_id is a string(using square connect with cloud functions)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, square-connect

I have made a cloud function to create and complete a payment request to square connect API.

This is the function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var SquareConnect = require("square-connect");
var defaultClient = SquareConnect.ApiClient.instance;

exports.sqProcessPayments = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .firestore.document("users/{userId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    var accessToken = "access--token";
    let previousData = change.before.data();
    let updatedData = change.after.data();
    let previousNonce = previousData["payment_nonce"];
    let updatedNonce = updatedData["payment_nonce"];
    if (previousNonce !== updatedNonce) {
      var oauth2 = defaultClient.authentications["oauth2"];
      oauth2.accessToken = accessToken;
      var idempotencyKey = new Date();
      var apiInstance = new SquareConnect.PaymentsApi();
      var body = new SquareConnect.CreatePaymentRequest({
        source_id: updatedNonce.toString(),
        idempotency_key: idempotencyKey.toString(),
        amount_money: {
        amount: 10,
        currency: "USD",
        },
        location_id: "location-id",
        autocomplete: true,
      });
      apiInstance
        .createPayment(body)
        .then(
          function (data) {
            console.log(
              "API called successfully. Returned data: " + data.payment.id
            ); 
            return data;
          },
          function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        )
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      }
    });
```

But I am getting this error on running this function

> '{"errors": [{"code": "EXPECTED_STRING","detail": "Expected a string value (line 1, character 14)","field": "source_id","category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"}]}\n'

I have checked the value of `source_id` and it is a string. But the error says otherwise.

Please help me resolve this. Any help would be great.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this in [CreatePaymentRequest](https://github.com/square/connect-nodejs-sdk/blob/6a6467ddd6c80197f54da52485ed660aaf4c54d0/src/model/CreatePaymentRequest.js#L65) code. This problem is related with creation of `body` object.

I think proper syntax will be:

```
var body = SquareConnect.CreatePaymentRequest.constructFromObject({
        source_id: updatedNonce.toString(),
        idempotency_key: idempotencyKey.toString(),
        amount_money: {
                amount: 10,
                currency: "USD",
        },
        location_id: "location-id",
        autocomplete: true,
      });
```

Or you can use:

```
var body = new SquareConnect.CreatePaymentRequest(
    updatedNonce.toString(),
    idempotencyKey.toString(),
    amount_money: {
                    amount: 10,
                    currency: "USD",
            }
 )
```

but in this situation you can only add `source_id`, `idempotency_key` and `amount_money`. Nothing more...